# Change volume with spotify App API

Tags: api, spotify

I was wondering if someone has succefully managed to change the volume with the [spotify app API](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/4f52ebf870.html)

I can without hassle change the playstate with `player.playing = true;` but `player.volume=0.5` will not work. Must I add a observer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the Player object does indeed say that you can set `volume` as a float from 0.0 to 1.0.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/f19ff300f8.html

It's possible you're only allowed to change the volume if your app initiated the playback that's occurring.